# Making polygons slighty bigger QGIS 3.14.16-Pi

Tags: qgis-3

I am not much of a programmer, but I have been using QGIS for about a year now to do fibre planning. I use the Atlas print to PDF feature to print the suburb plans with a block overlay layer to print individual blocks of a suburb. Around all the blocks there lines representing fibre lines, and on these lines there are points representing access points. In this week I started using  rule based symbology and labelling where I would use the following code in each layer to turn off all layers except the layer that is active on the atlas:

within($geometry, @atlas_geometry )=1

This works great if the polygon covers everything in the block in question, including the lines and points around the block.

My blocks where generated by a Model in QGIS that was written by someone else, and only covers the erven within the block, and not the surrounding lines and points, which I need to print as well. So this is what I am getting in my print layout at the moment. Only the addresses and the block's label:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

All Addresses are showing, including the erven lines, the lines around the block and the point around the block with their labels.

The problem is that all 128 blocks I need to export to PDF as individual pages, are all too small. I need to slightly enlarge each polygon to include the points and lines around it.

I have tried affine transform, buffer vectors and transforms vector layer without success. I read that the grass v.transform might be able to perform this function, but it gives an error when I run it:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Modifying your code to `within($geometry, buffer(@atlas_geometry,XX,25) )=1` should work, where `XX` is the distance you might need to cover.

Comment: Thanks, in what measure would the XX be? points, meters. I tried the following:

`within($geometry, buffer(@atlas_geometry,10,25) )=1`

But now it just displays permanently, regardless if it is in focus on the Atlas.

Comment: Which CRS is the layer covering your atlas using @WernerLeRoux? Since `buffer` uses CRS-units, a layer using degree will be buffered in degree.

Comment: Hi, CRS is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic

Comment: Seems to be Degrees. But does not matter what I make the values, it just displays permanently, regardless if it is in focus on the atlas.

Comment: Yeah, because you're buffering your polygons using degree. Reproject your atlas-layer to a m-based CRS, then my solution will work properly.

Comment: I still do not have a solution on this. 

Is there no other way of just making polygons slightly bigger? I just need to resize all polygons by a couple of meters. I tried the affine and v.stranform functions, without success. I tried changing the CRS to various other CRS's, without success. 

I just do not have the required knowledge on CRS systems to figure this out. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't ever simply change/set the CRS of a layer - you need to reproject it. Either by saving it to a new file, or using the `reproject/transform` tool @WernerLeRoux

Comment: Erik, thanks. I did a reprojection of the CRS, but it still did not give me the solution I am looking for.

Comment: BTW, I am now on QGIS 3.18.1.

Comment: Which CRS did you reproject to? How does the solution not meet your expectations @WernerLeRoux?